# Tag synonym request: [mekakucity-actors] syn'd to parent tag [kagerou-project]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

A user has just asked the question "[What does Headphone Actor represent or mean?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/9942/1908)" and tagged it with both [kagerou-project](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kagerou-project) and [mekakucity-actors](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mekakucity-actors). In light of this, I request that a moderator make [mekakucity-actors](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mekakucity-actors) a synonym of [kagerou-project](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kagerou-project). The name for the franchise as a whole is "Kagerou Project", with "Mekakucity Actors" only being the title of the anime.

(As is usual on this site, it will take until the heat death of the universe to collect 5 users with 1250 rep and a net answer score of 5 in [kagerou-project](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kagerou-project), all of whom decide to visit the tag-synonymization page, hence the request to moderators.)

Comment: Mission accomplished.